# Fetch Bounced emails from Office 365 mailbox using Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I had a SSIS package that was fetching unread emails from a mailbox using Outlook Autodiscovery(**Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll**).
Our organization had now moved to Office 365 and everything is on cloud now. I am now rewriting my package to use Microsoft Graph.

I have to fetch all the unread bounced emails and take subsequent actions on them. Previously, I was able to check for bounced email by checking on the ItemClass:

```
// Check if its bounced mail
if (message.ItemClass == "REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR")
```

Is there any similar property in MS Graph or any alternate approach to get bounced emails?

Currently, I am using the "**From**" attribute for this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages?$search="from:MAILER-DAEMON@mg1.dhs.state.gov"
```

But I don't want to rely on the from-email-address (it might change). Would prefer a more robust way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access ItemClass property, you can do that by expanding `SingleValueExtendedProperty`: `String 0x001A (0x001A001F)`.

[GetMessageWithExtendedProperty](https://github.com/ivfranji/GraphManagedApi/blob/43724a68dd7d6627511051c2fb3c3652ed3bd80b/src/Microsoft.Graph.ManagedAPI.FunctionalTests/FunctionalTests/MessageTestDefinition.cs#L24)

Comment: Not sure how it can help determine if the mail is bounced email or a regular email?

Comment: 0x001A001F will contain ItemClass value, pretty much same as your example above: message.ItemClass == "REPORT.IPM.Note.NDR".