# Retrieve bounce email and bcc email Microsoft Graph API .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to retrieve the bcc and bounced back email and move them to another folder called "Done". We use exchange 365

I tried [Fetch Bounced emails from Office 365 mailbox using Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59490404/fetch-bounced-emails-from-office-365-mailbox-using-microsoft-graph) and [How to trace back bounced messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336835/how-to-trace-back-bounced-messages)

It seems that it's for graph API URL. I am trying to use the .net Core graph API plugin.

I am Unable to figure out what the filter looks like in c# as per below "MissingFilter"

```
 var emails =  graphClient.Me.MailFolders.Inbox.Request().Select(x => x.SingleValueExtendedProperties == "MissingFilter"
```

I try to find out what is SingleValueExtendedProperties and it turns out to be an interface called IMailFolderSingleValueExtendedPropertiesCollectionPage. I am not sure which class that I can use which inherit that interface to create the filter.

Any advices for the filter?

In addition, any sample c# code for moving the messges to "Done" folder? I tried to google and most of the results come up with POST method rather than the .net core plugin. Thanks.

Comment: I would try first the above call works in MS Graph explorer or POSTMAN as well. Being said that i would try the above query like this - GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/AAMkAGE1M2_bs88AACHsLqWAAA=/?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id%20eq%20'String%20{66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00047ec6ac6e}%20Name%20Color')

In your scenario, replace the singlevalueextendedproperty that you're looking for and add the related value...

hope this helps.

Comment: Does this helped?

Comment: I have seen that doc before. Would like to know more about the C# graph api. I believe I have figured it out but its a bit long winded steps.

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: yep ,, just create a rule in outlook to direct all the emails into a folder. and read the emails from there using graph api